# HTML Tables info

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if there was any way to make tables in html to look exactly like this:

http://i43.tinypic.com/21dml8l.png

I basicly need 1 big cell, in first column, and then 9 cells in second column.

Is that possible to do?

Comment: +1 for providing a very clear picture of what you want to achieve. Not many people can manage to get their point across. However, next time you should really put some effort into answering the question yourself, showing us what you're tried so far, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I will listen to your advice.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3D69e/12/

Comment: You should use the tbody also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="9">
      Cell
    </td>
    <td>
      Cell 1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Cell 2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Cell 3
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Cell 4
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Cell 5
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Cell 6
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Cell 7
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Cell 8
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Cell 9
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You're missing a lot of rows there... And where does the table end?

Comment: You only have 1 row there! With 9 columns. This looks like http://jsfiddle.net/YuG26/ not what the OP was looking.

Comment: Fixed markup, my browser ate most of it. Answer is now [correct](http://jsfiddle.net/2g7zq/).

Comment: Wow had the problem again, seems like running webdriver for stresstesting in the background messes with the browser.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, first row (`<tr>`) has one `<td>` with `rowspan=9`, and then 8 other rows (`<tr>`) with one simple `<td>`.

Comment: Thanks, I needed explanation too.

Answer (score 2):

Based off PizzaPill's answer, and CyberDude's explanation, you should have:

```
<table> 
  <tr> 
    <td rowspan="9">Cell</td> 
    <td>Cell 1</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Cell 2</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Cell 3</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Cell 4</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Cell 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Cell 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Cell 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Cell 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Cell 9</td>
    </tr>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YuG26/1/

Remember to have 2 `<td>`'s in the first row and one in the following rows. You can add your styling as you wish.