# Weird table formatting in Outlook 2010

Tags: html, css, outlook, xhtml, html-table

I have searched and searched and couldn't find the answer.

I have strange problem, shown only in Outlook 2010.

[image: My problem]

As you can see in the image, I have one big table cell (behind the image), and on the other side, on the right (not in the image) table with 9 cells, same structure used in my question which can be found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327049/html-tables-info)

Now, I don't understand why Outlook 2010 is not rendering my code properly, and why do I have those black lines (spacing maybe?) on both sides of the image.

Here is my current code, I may have overlooked something... :(

```
<td rowspan="9"><img alt="Image" src="http://imagelink.com" width="177" height="177" style="margin:15px 0 10px 20px;border-style:solid;border-color:#fff;border-width:7px;-webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 7px 1px #cecece;-moz-box-shadow:0 3px 7px 1px #cecece;box-shadow:0 3px 7px 1px #cecece"></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First,** there is not enough info here to duplicate the problem. I copied your exact scenario from the link provided with the snippet above.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="9"><img alt="Image" src="http://imagelink.com" width="177" height="177" style="margin:15px 0 10px 20px;border-style:solid;border-color:#fff;border-width:7px;-webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 7px 1px #cecece;-moz-box-shadow:0 3px 7px 1px #cecece;box-shadow:0 3px 7px 1px #cecece">
    </td>
    <td>
        Cell 1
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Cell 2
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Cell 3
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Cell 4
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Cell 5
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Cell 6
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Cell 7
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Cell 8
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Cell 9
    </td>
</tr>
</table>​
```

Tested it in Outlook 2010 on Windows 7. No problems. Please include the exact markup. Headers and body content can affect the email.

**Second,** what machine you are using, Outlook appears differently in XP than 7.

**Third,** you should not use shorthand CSS for emails. See: http://sixrevisions.com/web_design/creating-html-emails/

**Fourth,** paddings and margins only work on tables and td tags if they are to be cross email-client compatible: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/. Margins however are not supported in Hotmail. Without nesting the image into another table as per the link, you will have padding/margin issues with inner content on the first row.

**Fifth,** you need to close all your tags. The image did not have it's closing /.

*I hunch that you may have to use nested tables here, as it may be an email client display issue. There is a section on that here: Campaignmonitor has an excelent section for design-guidelines*

Try this:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr>                   
                <td style="padding-top: 15px; padding-right:0px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left:20px;" width="177px" height="177px">
                    <img alt="Image" src="http://imagelink.com" width="177px" height="177px" style="border-style:solid; border-color:#ffffff; border-width:7px; -webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 7px 1px #cecece; -moz-box-shadow:0 3px 7px 1px #cecece; box-shadow:0 3px 7px 1px #cecece" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>            
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Cell 1
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Cell 2
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Cell 3
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Cell 4
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Cell 5
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Cell 6
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Cell 7
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Cell 8
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Cell 9
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>​
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm an idiot, i didn't include / at the end of img tag and that was the problem, everything works now perfectly. Sorry for such a rookie mistake and thanks!